# Unable to download more than 16144 characters when requesting json from API

Tags: java, android, json, http, download

I have an android application which downloads its information as JSON.

A typical JSON download is about 2,000-3,000 characters. But i wanted to stress it, so I created a larger file (~48,000 characters). As files go this is still small, under 50kb.

The problem I have is when downloading I am only getting 16144 charcters of data. That is `reader.readLine()` returns just one line containing 16144 characters, as does `client.execute(request, new BasicResponseHandler());`. Obviously with only part of the file, my JSON parsering code fails quickly as its not a valid JSON object.

There are no exceptions raised, so its not an out of memory error. And the problem is repeatable on a HTC desire (2.2) and Galaxy Nexus (4.1.1), so not OS specific either. I've tested the URL in a web browser and it works fine, all the JSON is available so its not a server error.

**Question**

Can anyone point out why it is downloading only 16144 characters, and how to make it download the whole file?

**Method #1**

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
    str.append(line);
}
in.close();
result.setJSONResult(str.toString());
```

**Method #2**

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

String json = client.execute(request, new BasicResponseHandler());
result.setJSONResult(json);
```

Note - The url is on a LAN network (http://192.168.0.99:8080...), so I've not included it as it won't be useful.

**Update - Fixed**

Fixed the problem. In the end I put it down to a file transfer issue rather than memory limits of the phone. Whilst it worked on a PC (Chrome), I found it was broken in other places other than on android such as on the website and other browsers (Safari) didn't work with the raw API call. The underlying problem was the webserver's proxy ngix, wanted to buffer larger responses (over 32kb) however it never had write permissions on the server folders it used for buffering. This meant it sent part of the file, started to buffer and hit a critial error due to been unable to write. When it errored, it stopped sending the rest of the file hence it stopping at an unusual number of bytes. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: its because that's the max size a string can hold --  always 2147483647 (2^31 - 1) by the Java specification, the maximum size of an array, which the String class uses for internal storage) or half your maximum heap size (since each character is two bytes), whichever is smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem. In the end I put it down to a file transfer issue rather than memory limits of the phone. Whilst it worked on a PC (Chrome), I found it was broken in other places other than on android such as on the website and other browsers (Safari) didn't work with the raw API call. The underlying problem was the webserver's proxy ngix, wanted to buffer larger responses (over 32kb) however it never had write permissions on the server folders it used for buffering. This meant it sent part of the file, started to buffer and hit a critial error due to been unable to write. When it errored, it stopped sending the rest of the file hence it stopping at an unusual number of bytes. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

its because that's the max size a string can hold -- always 2147483647 (2^31 - 1) by the Java specification, the maximum size of an array, which the String class uses for internal storage) or half your maximum heap size (since each character is two bytes), whichever is smaller.

and probably the heap size ll be less than 40kbs

you can use json reader instead of using a string to store the data from web pls refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Comment: its the heap size of your device if testing on an emulator check the heap size it ll be less than 40 kb any ways that's why

Comment: to check click the avd manager and then cselect the avd click edit

Comment: I would prefer not to use a 3rd party JSON parser. We have written the code to parse the JSON ourselves, using just JSONObject and JSONArray from within the standard android library. The system was under heavy development and the JSON we get back can differ significantly so using conditional logic in our own parser seemed the best way to go to handle the JSON received.

Comment: @JonWillis its not a 3rd party reader it comes default in android

Comment: @droidhot, my apologies i've been looking at Newton JSON and GJSON libraries and assume it was part of that. I'll read into it, however this problem now looks like a big job re-writing how I turn the JSON into our in-memory object. The code above is used to call several apis and a string return is expected (later parsed using JSONObject), although this test I am doing is the only one that has a potentially large response.

Comment: Looking at heap sizes, shouldn't the application have 32MB available. So in theory holding a 40kb string shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: you can try saving to a text file and later consuming it or splitting the response from server which ll always be @ limited size and adding something like a boolean furherdata to get the balace data by connecting again - i m using this approach (blnc data available)

Comment: you can consume only half of the heap size (pls note)

Comment: I don't believe saving to file will help. Looking at the JSONObject docs, I must put in a string. If the string is incomplete that is it does not contain the start and end of the JSON it will fail (which is what is happening now, only about 1/3 is loaded). I need the whole string in memory at once.

Comment: yap so you should either use 1 of them jsonreader or server side implimentation

Comment: StringBuilder sbtest = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
sbtest.append("A");
}
sbtest.append("B");
String test = sbtest.toString();
This writes 100,001 characters to a string. So having more than 16,144 is possible. So it doesn't look like a heap limitation. If my string was large >1MB i could understand but 40kb of string is so small.

Comment: it depend on the mobiles memory availability

Comment: I've been trying to save the JSON to file just to test the download of the data. No matter how I try to download the JSON either in one go or stream it, I always get 16,144 bytes of data before it cuts off. How would you recommend downloading the content of the URL and saving to file. I.ve tried as you can see above HttpClient, but just now URLConnection as well. Both cut out when downloading 16,144 bytes of data, even if I buffer and write to file in 1024 chunks.

Comment: never gave a try (i hope the best soln is requesting the web service to give a lesser amount of data and ask for the bal again if available )

Comment: Also spotted I can't use JSONReader. I didn't say but we have to support API 8 and JSONReader its API 11. I'm still going to try it now to see if it can read it. However, I get the feeling android just isn't downloading all the data and the problem is with that rather than memory. I am requesting as little data as possible, this is single object but just me stress testing it.

Comment: Fixed the problem. I put it down to a file download issue. Whilst it worked on a PC (Chrome), I found it was broken in other places other than android such as on the website and other browsers (Safari) didn't work with it. The underlying problem was the webserver's proxy ngix, wanted to buffer larger files however it never had write permissions. This meant it sent part of the file and hit a critial error due to been unable to write. When it errored, it stopped sending the rest of the file. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

You are using a line-based reader to read data that is not line-based. When you call `readLine`, you are asking it to forcefully convert whatever it read into a line of text. This mangles the data if it's not in fact a line of text.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i'm not sure if this is the problem. The JSON does contain textual data that includes newlines as \n, however these appear to be ignored, that is several of them are read in that one statement reader.readLine() and if I have less than 16,000 characters in a response it works fine. The 16144 character is located in the middle of a word which to me indicates a different underlying problem. But I am going to try reader.read() in a moment and try it one char at a time.